At MariaDB database suddenly huge number of bin log file generated
I found almost 13830 update rows found like below in each bin logs files. But there are only a few update queries at each log.
This command shows only 85 update query
mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.005400 | grep -i 'Update' | grep -i '#Q> UPDATE' | wc -l
For this below command show 13830 rows like the below output.
mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.005400 | grep -i 'Update' | grep -i 'Update_rows: table id' | wc -l 
Log Output:

server id 1  end_log_pos 108614456 CRC32 0xfe8e56d5    Update_rows: table id 49992010

What is the table id here?
Why does it show that huge number of the above output?
How do I find that specific table based on id?

If the binary log format is ROW, then a TABLE_MAP_EVENT event will be sent before the ROWS_EVENT (which contains update/insert or delete information). The TABLE_MAP_EVENT contains information about table id and name.
Example:
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1),(2);

Binary log shows:
#240713  8:46:59 server id 1  end_log_pos 0 CRC32 0x6f2c3407    Table_map: `test`.`t1` mapped to number 22
# at 785
#240713  8:46:59 server id 1  end_log_pos 0 CRC32 0x221bb533    Write_rows: table id 22 flags: STMT_END_F

BINLOG '
4yKSZhMBAAAALQAAAAAAAAAAABYAAAAAAAEABHRlc3QAAnQxAAEDAAEHNCxv
4yKSZhcBAAAAKwAAAAAAAAAAABYAAAAAAAEAAQH+AQAAAP4CAAAAM7UbIg==
'/*!*/;
# Number of rows: 2

